# Access from view to object in appdelegate

Tags: iphone

I would like to acces to a object in appdelegate from diferent views. I mean, in the appdelegate I have a object which I need in diferent view but I don't know how get the instance. 
In my app, I have only one object with information from the user and I need this data from diferents views.

Answer (score 0):

yourObject* obj = [(YourAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] yourObject];

Comment: one question, Have I release after use obj?

Comment: No. You should read memory management guide :
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html